# how do I access the file_id in this list?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

i'm trying to access file_id but its in a list.

this is a part of the code `update.message.photo.file_id`

i am getting this error: `'list' object has no attribute 'file_id'`

here's the json file:

```
{
  'update_id': 703304245,
  'message': {
    'photo': [
      {
        'width': 90,
        'height': 51,
        'file_id': 'AgACAgQAAx0CU5MMFAACDgFj_wV1c6WOBWXU_GYGLwT9BV9cngACw7sxG93l-VMAAfavUwejsMMBAAMCAANzAAMuBA',
        'file_size': 1293,
        'file_unique_id': 'AQADw7sxG93l-VN4'
      },
    ],
```

Comment: It's a dict with key `photo`, which has value that is list of dicts, and these dict(s) have key `file_id`

Comment: Your error message is strange. It looks like you could actually get the `photo` list. But that shouldn't be possible by attribute access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it this way:

```
file['message']['photo'][0]['file_id']
```

I presumed this dictionary is called file

Answer (score 0):

`your_dictionary['message']['photo'][0]['file_id']`

And replace `'your_dictionary'` with the name of the file, I think, or call it something when you're accessing it?

Essentially, there is a list inside the nested dictionary, and to get the dictionary inside it out you need to get the first element [0] from that list

Alternatively a json parsing function could help?